# Improper "Your Sites" User Interface

Tags: bug, android-app

Why are the sites so far from each other? It looks like improper UI.

> [image]

Two consecutive items are at a distance of about *¾ of screen height*.

Also kindly tell me what the *three parallel horizontal line* at the beginning of the sites do.

Comment: @Cai  Exactly. But there's no answer.

Comment: No, doesn't matter though, there's no point in leaving open multiple bug reports. Unfortunately doesn't seem to be much development on the Android app at the moment so unlikely anything will be done about it soon.